# Does exiting the battle after getting killed affect the scoring?

Tags: world-of-tanks

After I'm killed in a battle, can I just press ESC, pick another tank and play another battle without any penalties, or will the outcome (credits, experience) be adversely affected unless I spectate until the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you get the same rewards.  Whether you spectate or not once you're out has no effect on credits and xp.

Comment: In fact this is a tip shown by the game when the map loads.